# Timed behaviors in Akka classic?

Tags: java, akka

I am working with Akka classic, and have to setup timed behaviors - in Akka typed, I could do this using `Behaviors.withTimers` how do I accomplish this in Akka classic? It seems like we can create an actor in Akka using

```java
public static Props props() {
    return Props.create(actor.class, () -> new actor());
}
```

How do I use timers in this kind of initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs on Timers: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#timers-scheduled-messages

In short, mixin the Timers trait. Then you can use `timers` to access the API. You'll receive messages in response to the timers firing.

```
class MyActor extends Actor with Timers {
  import MyActor._
  timers.startSingleTimer(TickKey, FirstTick, 500.millis)

  def receive = {
    case FirstTick =>
      // do something useful here
      timers.startTimerWithFixedDelay(TickKey, Tick, 1.second)
    case Tick =>
    // do something useful here
  }
}
```